# How does one disable SourceDestCheck when creating instances with AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

It should be possible to disable SourceDestCheck since [it is documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)
"SourceDestCheck -> (boolean)"

but using run-instances with

```
aws ec2 run-instances ...
--SourceDestCheck false
```

or

```
--sourceDestCheck=false
```

Fails with
Unknown options: --SourceDestCheck, false

It seems I can run it later with a modify command

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --resource=$INSTANCE_ID --no-source-dest-check
```

but it should be possible to set that at instantiation. I just can't figure out the actual syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but I ran into the same issue today and solved it this way.  In the resource block of your terraform file add:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --no-source-dest-check --instance-id ${self.id}"
}
```

assuming you have the was cli tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't set that on initial launch with the AWS CLI. It's [not a supported option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html). You have to call `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --no-source-dest-check` documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @mark pointed out, this isn't an option in the [RunInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html#API_RunInstances_RequestParameters) API. I just want to add that the `SourceDestCheck` in the AWS CLI doc you referenced is an output. If you look closely, it's an attribute of the ENI.